# Show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $||\mathbf{x}||<\delta$, then $||f(\mathbf{x})||<\varepsilon |g(\mathbf{x})|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Question Background: This question is not for marks/homework. I am simply having trouble working out a concrete proof.

Question: Suppose $f(\mathbf{x})=o(g(\mathbf{x}))$. Show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $||\mathbf{x}||<\delta$, then $||f(\mathbf{x})||<\varepsilon |g(\mathbf{x})|$

My start at a proof: We are given that
$$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim}\frac{||f(\mathbf{x})||}{|g(\mathbf{x})|}=0$$

Now let us choose an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $||\mathbf{x}||<\delta$. Then we have
$$||f(\mathbf{x})|| < \varepsilon$$
$$\Longrightarrow ||o(g(\mathbf{x}))|| < \varepsilon$$

I am not sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Style note, once you've chosen an arbitrary $\epsilon$, the "for all $\epsilon > 0$" immediately after does not make sense. Anyway, I would consider plugging in your chosen $\epsilon$ into the definition of the limit that you assume exists (should that be $n \to \infty$ or something else?).  Note that the limit assumed to exist is of $\|f\|/\|g\|$, not of $\|f\|$.  You will get a $\delta$ providing a condition under which $\|f(x)\|/\|g(x)\| < \epsilon$ is assured. Then maybe see what else will happen under that condition on $\delta$.